# jplayer isn't showing progress bar or seek bar on IE

Tags: javascript, jplayer

I am using jplayer to play mp3 files and for some reason, the seek bar isn't showing up on IE9, and on IE8, I am not seeing the progress bar or the seek bar...  has anyone experienced this issue before?